# Javascript Papaparse Select specific columns using Lodash _.pick() results in empty data

Tags: javascript, papaparse

As stated in previous questions here and on Google, I've added a step function to alter the data and provide me with the specific columns I need.
Here was a comment that said to use Lodash _.pick() method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59944480/4236332

However, when doing that I end up with a completely empty results output.

Code:

```
parseFile(){
    Papa.parse( this.file, {
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
            step: (results, parser) => {
               results.data = _.pick(results.data , [ 'column1', 'column2']);
               return results;
            },
            complete: function( results ){
                 console.log(results.data)
                 this.content = results;
                 this.parsed = true;
            }.bind(this)
     });
}
```

Before vs. After:

[image: 1]

First console log holds the colums in the JSON I need plus several I want to filter out, Second log is completely empty.

Tried removing it from the step function and doing it in the complete function but same output.

EDIT 1:
I have tried testing the _.pick function on results.data[0] and this does work, so something is preventing _.pick() of looping through all json records in the list results.data?

Comment: You didn't show what an object looks like, it's not confirmed that 'column1', etc really exist. The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It does exist, I just did not want to show the information it holds. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this issue by looping through it with a _.map() function. This way it goes through every object in the array with the ._pick() method.

```
results.data = _.map(results.data, obj => _.pick(obj, [ 'column1','column2']));
```